# Post object show term name

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy-terms

How can i show the term name thats linked to the post of a post object (ACF)?

With this code i can see the title of that post:

```
get_the_title( get_field('which_game')->ID );
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information about what you need, e.g. is it a category name,  a tag name or a custom taxonomy? Also, posts can have more than one associated term, so do you want to get all of them?

Comment: @FluffyKitten it's a custom taxonomy that is connect to the post.

Comment: OK, what is the taxonomy name, and what about if there is more than one term?

Comment: @FluffyKitten hi, its "provider" and it's alwasy only one. I edit the question with a little more code the only thing is that is displaying all terms in the custom taxonomie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the term names for a post, you can use either of these functions:

1. [wp_get_post_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/)
2. [get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)

They work the same way but have slightly different argument lists, and more crucially `get_the_terms` works on cached data (making it quicker) whereas `wp_get_post_terms` doesn't.

```
$postObj = get_field('which_game');

// DEPENDING ON WHICH FUNCTION YOU WANT TO USE:
$terms = get_the_terms( $postObj->ID, 'provider');
// OR 
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $postObj->ID, 'provider' array( 'fields' => 'name') );

// Both functions return arrays, even if there is just 1 term
// so loop through the terms returned to add the names to an array
foreach ($terms as $term) 
    $term_names[] = $term->name;

// turn the array into a comma-separated string (of just the name on its own if there is just 1)
$term_name_str =  implode("','",$term_names);
```

If you are sure you will only have 1 term you could just check that there are any results returned and then get the first one:

```
if (count($terms) > 1) 
    $term_name_str = $terms[0]->name;
```

However, the first example works well for just 1 term and is more flexible.

*Note - this code is untested so it might have a few syntax errors, but the basic concept is correct.*

Comment: It's not working, its displaying nothing, i used the first $terms. I think the problem is if i do '$string .= $postObj->ID;' i also dont get any ID visible?

Comment: @Maanstraat  What is `$string .= $postObj->ID;`? You don't have that in your question. Also did you change the variable names so that they are all either `$post_object` or `$postObj`? Also, have you checked the ID by doing `var_dump( get_field('which_game')->ID); var_dump( $postObj->ID);`?

Comment: Stupid of me i see it now its outputing the title of the "main" post and not the post i linked it with! So what i have is post type A and post type B in post type A i have a "Post Object" field made to link a post from post type B. So now i want to show info from a post in post type B into post type A. i already selected a post in post type A, so they are connected.

Comment: @Maanstraat I'm not quite clear on what you want to do there, but it doesn't look like it is to do with getting the term names? It looks like it is a different question, and each question on SO should be about 1 specific problem at a time :) You can add a new question for that problem, I suggest also giving an example of what you want to do to help make it clear.